# What's the difference between View and ContentView when creating my custom control in Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, mobile, controls, custom-controls

What's the difference between View and  ContentView when creating my custom control in Xamarin?

Comment: You can read the offical documents about the ContentView and View at first. In addition, you can understand the difference about them clearly by reading the resource code.

Comment: Gee! Thanks a lot. You are so helpful. I didn't know I needed to read the official documents and in addition understand the difference.